# Why do HTTP operations need to be Idempotent when we have TCP/IP?

Tags: http, networking, rest, tcp

Why do we need HTTP GET, PUT, or DELETE to be idempotent if TCP/IP is a reliable protocol that will retry requests on our behalf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TCP/IP does not retry *requests*, it retransmits the original *packets* that make up each request, if necessary.

If a *request* fails (at the HTTP layer) it's the job of the client to retry it, not the network stack.

In particular, if the client (for what ever reason) fails to receive the response code indicating whether a RESTful operation succeeded or not, the client must be able to resend the same operation without having to worry about any unintended side effects.

These failures *can* happen - an intermediate firewall might have timed-out the connection while the server was processing the operation.  The server won't know that this has happened, as soon as it has received the request it has to carry on regardless.

Comment: What kind of request failure needs to be retried at the HTTP layer but not at the packet level?

Comment: 502 Bad Gateway, 504 Gateway Timeout, 500 Internal Server Error (say, database timed out)
It's what causes the dreaded "triple post" in forums, reddit, etc.

Comment: Excellent point on timeouts. So what we're saying is that TCP/IP guarantees that the server receives our request, but the client might time-out before the server carries out the operation. Clients expect to be able to retry later on without duplicating the original operation. Can you please update the answer with this explanation?

Comment: @Gili TCP does not guarantee that the two sides will agree on whether or not data was exchanged. If you send a request and the connection breaks before you get a reply, you do not know if the other side processed the request or not.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Good example!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing Idempotency at the HTTP-protocol level with byte-stream reliability at the TCP level.

### HTTP Idempotency:

[Idempotent (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_meaning) means that sending the same HTTP request 10 times has the same effect as doing it once.

### TCP reliability:

If you lose a packet in a TCP stream, it will be retransmitted.  But the application-protocol (HTTP) has no knowledge that TCP had to retransmit packets.

Even if an individual packet containing a complete HTTP request is retransmitted 10 times by TCP, the browser/server will only see one HTTP request.  The reason TCP retransmits is because of packet loss, but application-protocols (like HTTP) have no knowledge that TCP had to retransmit.  They seem the same request with or without packet loss

Comment: @Mike: I understand the difference. I don't understand why you would need to repeat the same (PUT or DELETE) request 10 times unless it was due to a dropped packet.

Comment: @Gili, that is precisely the point.  You **do not** need to repeat an `HTTP PUT` or any other HTTP command due to a packet retransmission.  HTTP requests are repeated because of human (or robot) behavior (hitting reload in their browser)...

Comment: @Mike: You provide a good explanation of Idempotency and TCP reliability but fail to explain why Clients would ever need to repeat a request (users/robots do not repeat an operation without a reason).

Comment: @Gili, I don't even understand why that is relevant; please elaborate on why it matters

Comment: @Mike, why should we protect users from repeating a purchase request? Maybe they really *do* want to purchase the same item twice? My point is that unless you understand why requests are being repeated it isn't clear why you should protect against it. Without concrete examples this comes across as a business-logic decision instead of something that belongs in the HTTP-layer.

Comment: @Gili I never said anything about protecting users from a duplicate request.  If you want to know why people repeat HTTP requests, think about why you keep repeating HTTP GETs to [**this link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870232/why-do-http-operations-need-to-be-idempotent-when-we-have-tcp-ip) over and over again

Comment: @Mike, I understand why HTTP GET needs to have no side-effects (since users need to poll for updates) but why should the same be true for PUT or DELETE?

Comment: @Gili, I don't know.  Perhaps you can ask another question on SO.  We have thoroughly exhausted the scope of your original question, and we've now entered new territory.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP's GET, PUT, and DELETE are idempotent because, in some network failure modes, the client cannot know whether the request completed or how fully.

For example, if a client requests a DELETE of a resource, but the server closes the connection before the complete response is received by the client, the client does not know whether the resource was deleted or not. The client then has a dilemma: perhaps the operation failed, in which case the DELETE should be re-sent in order to advance the application to the desired state. But perhaps it succeeded; will sending the same DELETE request work if I retry? Perhaps it will work. Perhaps it will return a 500 error (which just adds to the client's confusion). Perhaps it will apply to a different resource! The idempotency requirement allows the client to be confident that they can retry the request and have it work. That doesn't mean you'll get exactly the same response; the first request might receive 200 OK and the second 404 Not Found or 410 Gone. But the client doesn't have to worry about unintended side-effects from retries.

Comment: So you're saying HTTP is idempotent in order to deal with misconfigured TCP/IP connections? I don't think you can get connection resets under normal conditions.

Comment: HTTP is designed to work well even in conditions where resets are very "normal". It's not about misconfiguration; it's about performing properly even under load at large scale. Any large website has learned to accept that some portion of their machines will be failing on a constant basis. HTTP allows them to design applications that can survive that reality.

Comment: cf http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.4 TCP connections, especially request/response style, can have very nasty timing issues that have nothing to do with configuration.